# Repeat delayed task n times

Tags: java, android, postdelayed

i want to run a portion of code n times with delay of some seconds.

here is my code:

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("myLog","Runnable()-->Run()");
               // do a task here
        }
    };

Handler handler = new Handler();
    // loop repeating task 6 times
    for (int count = 0; count < 6; count++){
        Log.e("Log","Task loop "+count);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);    // run task after 20 seconds
    }
```

**Problem:** the for loop running all the tasks concurrently. i want to run delayed task one by one.

i found a answer at post :- 
[Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay)

but it repeating job infinite times.

i found very close logic to my question:-
[Bukkit Delayed Task Inside a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463608/bukkit-delayed-task-inside-a-for-loop)

but doesn't looks relevant to me

Comment: You need to chain the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 class RepeatableTask extends TimerTask{
    int repeats;
    Timer time;
    public RepeatableTask(int repeats){
        this.repeats=repeats;
    }
    void init(){
        time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(this,0,TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(delayInMinutes));
    }
    void stop(){
        time.cancel();
    }
    void run(){
        if(repeats == 0){stop();}
        new Thread->{
            //task
        }
        repeats--;
    }
}

//usage
RepeatableTask taskObject = new RepeatableTask(5);
taskObject.init();
```

Comment: i cant understand why these codes running the task two times more then given, if i pass 10 in RepeatableTask's constructor it run the task 12 times

Answer (score 1):

```
// Instance variable

private int counter = 0;
private int maxCounter = 6;

createTask(){
    if(counter<maxCount){
        counter++;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);
    }
}


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("myLog","Runnable()-->Run()");
               // do a task here

               createTask();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("myLog "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: tried this code, if im using runnable.run() job only ran once, when i used handler.postDelayed(runnable,20000) the job repeated 4 time then stopped

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
        int n=0;
        myHandler=new Handler();
        myRunnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do your task
                n++;
                if(n<=count)
                    myHandler.postDelayed(this,2000);


            }
        };
        myRunnable.run();
```

Comment: I didn't get you. `some api reference` means?

Comment: How about if java itself provide some code for repeating a task number of times with delay